# The result of AJAX call, jQuery .append() doesn't work with Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to .append() the result of an AJAX call in my Laravel 5.4 application but the appending doesn't work and I get no errors in my console.

ajax.js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#storeComment').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Retrieve form data
        var formData = new FormData();

        var data = $(this).serializeArray();
        $.each(data, function(index, field) {
            formData.set(field.name, field.value);

        });
        axios.post('/comments', formData, { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
            ).then(function(response) {
            let newComment = "<div class='comment'><p><strong>" + response.data.user.name + "</strong>" 
                + response.data.comment.created_at + "</p><p>" + response.data.comment.comment + "</p><hr></div>";
            console.log(newComment);

            $(".comments").append(newComment);
        });
    });
});

 console.log(newComment);
```

result:

```
<div class='comment'><p><strong>admin</strong>2018-10-10 06:39:20</p><p>a</p><hr></div>
```

html:

```
<div class="comments">
    @forelse ($imageRequest->comments as $comment)
     <div class="comment">
       <p><strong>{{ $comment->user->name }}</strong> {{$comment->created_at}}</p>
       <p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
       <hr>
     </div>
    @empty
       <p>@lang('image_request.show.nocomments')</p>
    @endforelse
</div>
```

The data is good, only the appending doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: could you try to change `.comments` class with `#comments` and also change tag attribute to `id="comments"` and then try.

Comment: Could you also provide the rest of the relevant html?

Comment: @LuckySaini I tried that, doesn't work either

Comment: @SvenHakvoort updated OP

Comment: `console.log($(".comments"))` does that print correct div class?

Comment: I have tried to make a minimal example in order to get it to work, as you can see here: https://codepen.io/svenhakvoort/pen/GYWBLP it should work with the way you do the append. So it probably goes wrong somewhere else in the code and not on the append, could you provide any other code which might be relevant and if there is any other output in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case error might have come but you haven't checked it: try to catch the error as below:

```
    axios.post('/comments', formData, { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
        ).then(function(response) {
        let newComment = "<div class='comment'><p><strong>" + response.data.user.name + "</strong>" 
            + response.data.comment.created_at + "</p><p>" + response.data.comment.comment + "</p><hr></div>";
        console.log(newComment);

        $(".comments").append(newComment);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
       // handle error
        console.log(error);
     });
```